# Package dependencies based on platform (or operating system) in Racket

Tags: package, racket, raco

I have a package that uses platform dependent system libraries, each of which are separated out into there own package. Is there a way I could install a different dependency based on what platform I am installing on?

The most naive solution would be to have the package depend on all of them:

```
#lang info
...
(define deps '("mypackage-windows" "mypackage-osx"))
```

But then `mypackage-windows` and `mypackage-osx` get installed even if they're not needed. Worse still, I then need to ensure that the OS X and Windows specific packages don't cause issues when installed on the wrong platform.

So, there any way I can tell `raco` to only install the packages that I need based on each platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is. You can use the `#:platform` symbol in the `deps` portion of your `info.rkt` file to do this.

You can find [documentation on it here](http://docs.racket-lang.org/pkg/metadata.html?q=deps#%28idx._%28gentag._3._%28lib._pkg%2Fscribblings%2Fpkg..scrbl%29%29%29), and an [example of it in the  racket-gui package](https://github.com/racket/gui/blob/master/gui-lib/info.rkt).

You can use `'osx` `'unix` and `'windows` to determine what platform you are on.

So your example would look like:

```
#lang info
...
(define deps '((mypackage-windows #:platform windows)
               (mypackage-osx     #:platform osx))
```

In fact, if you wanted to have a different version of your package that work differently on 36 and 64 (and even ppc) variants of each you can do that too:

```
#lang info
...
(define deps '((mypackage-windows-64 #:platform "win32\\x86_64")
               (mypackage-windows-32 #:platform "wind32\\i386")
               (mypackage-osx-64     #:platform "x86_64-macosx")
               (mypackage-osx-32     #:platform "i386-macosx")
               (mypackage-osx-ppc    #:platform "ppc-macosx")))
```

Comment: This answer came out of a discussion with Matthew on this PR: https://github.com/racket/racket/pull/1172